# Executing Javascript cells in Jupyter Notebooks

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm seeing some strange behavior using Javascript cells in a (trusted) Jupyter notebook.

For example, I can execute the following cells, intended to fetch the current URL of the notebook.

```
%%javascript
var kernel = IPython.notebook.kernel;
var thename = window.location.href;
var command = "notebook_url = " + "'"+thename+"'";
kernel.execute(command);
```

And now I try to access the variable in another cell:

```
print notebook_url
```

This works as expected with I run the cells one after another (Shift + Enter), but throws a `NameError: name 'notebook_url' is not defined` when I try to 'Run All' cells.

How could I get this to work with 'Run All'?

Comment: Doing 'run all' is more or less like JS doing `for (cell in cells) { kernel.execute(cell.source); }`. So the command you want to execute to set `notebook_url =` will only be run after all the cells in the notebook. That's why it doesn't work, and there's not really a good way to work around it.